# How to set up Arelle to export xbrl into other postgres schema than `public`?

Tags: python, postgresql, xbrl, arelle

[Here](http://arelle.org/documentation/xbrl-database/) is a documentation about xbrl data exporting into postgres. Also there are [XBRL-US](http://XBRL-US) and [Abstract Model](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/master/arelle/plugin/xbrlDB/sql/semantic/xbrlSemanticPostgresDB.ddl) sql scripts for postgres db. The documentation also points out that export can be done into different databases. But postgres supports different schemas in single database. How to change Arelle settings to export xbrl into different schema than `public`? (here I mean python code, for sql scripts text replace can be easyly done)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking the default PostgreSQL schema `public` with XBRL data-models. `public` is PostgreSQL specific, independent of Arelle or XBRL. To alter the XBRL data model, specify the `technology` parameter in the arelleCmdLine: `pgSemantic` will use the Abstract model, `postgres` will use the XBRL-US Public data-model.

In both cases the XBRL data will appear under the `public` schema in your PostgreSQL database.